# snap and emacs causing problems?

Tags: init-file

Odd problems:

I had to install EMACS via SNAP due to v26 not able to run org-roam and although that works now, I'm getting all sorts of odd problems.

My version now is
GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0)
of 2022-11-03

The debug reads:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "edit-server")
  require(edit-server)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/kantuck/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4077
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/kantuck/.emacs" "/home/kantuck/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1e0f4d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

The warning buffer when emacs starts reads:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load mu4e Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/kantuck/.emacs’:

Invalid read syntax: ), 1, 0

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. Disable showing Disable logging
```

I might also mention that I've been unable to keep the line wrapping set right as well. I have to reset it back via the options menu entry everytime I load EMACS or even load a new buffer

Also I have a 32b laptop (old asus eee) I use emacs on. I had to do the same; Snap install for 27.1.

For this, I get a similar problem error "occurred while loading /home/kantuck/.emacs  invalid read syntax:"

Should I just clone emacs from github and install it via that way to get 29? 26 didn't give me a single problem, aside from org-roam.

- Kantuck

Comment: It is complaining that your init file has at least one syntax error. Have you tried to fix that?

Comment: DId you try starting with `--debug-init` as the error message suggests? If so, did you get a backtrace? If you did, please edit your question and add the backtrace.

Comment: Yes, I did start a debug, and it's in the first question under "debug reads"

But now I think I found the problem; it was 3 aspects. I went though my .emacs pulled the entire then went back and put in each segment seeing what causes problems. 

edit-server looked to be a chrome/emacs connection that I no longer use. The 2nd is ";;Write good - http://bnbeckwith.com/code/writegood-mode.html" I'll research that, maybe it's not working with >26, and the last is mu4e. So thank you all, You can now close this question